# debian, discard dns from one interface

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, debian-jessie

I created a virtual machine with 2 network interfaces.
One is bridged and the other one is host-only.

They are both using DHCP, and are overwriting the /etc/resolv.conf file.

- if eth0 gets the DHCP response first then eth1 overwrites the file
  with the wrong DNS server address.
- if eth1 gets the DHCP response first then eth0 overwrites the file
  with the right address and everything is fine.

It would be ideal to just always take the DNS response from eth0 (bridged interface).

I had a look at /etc/dhcp/dhcpclient.conf but i couldn't find a way to create somekind of if here so that the dhcp client would only request a dns address from eth0

what would be the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I've found to solve this "issue" is installing **resolvconf** package.

```
sudo apt-get install resolvconf
```

After that, */etc/resolv.conf* is replaced by a symbolic link to */etc/resolvconf/run/resolv.conf* that is dynamically generated by **resolvconf** with the info from the file */etc/network/interfaces*

**Note that *dns-nameserver* entries in */etc/network/interfaces* are ignored if you don't have resolvconf package installed in your system**. You can find more info about the [**resolvconf** package info in Debian wiki documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#The_resolv.conf_configuration_file) or using man pages.

```
man resolvconf
```